# App-owned objects stories not showing in timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to publish a story with an app-owned object, I can create the object with $facebook->api('/app/objects/appnamespace:object', 'post', $post) and publish the story with $facebook->api('/'.$idFacebook.'/appnamespace:post', 'post', $post);

But nothing is on my timeline, even if I check "Shown on timeline" in Activity log.

If I publish the story with self-Hosted object (URL), and facebook scrape infos with header's tags and I check "Shown on timeline" in Activity log the story is showing up.

What is the difference, and why app-owned object dont shows up ?

P.S.: My story is not yep approuved.

Answer (score 0):

Create an app owned object needs of an **app-access token**.
Then when you create an app-owned object you do include the **app-access token**

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/books.book"  \
  -F "access_token=$APP_TOKEN" \
  -F "object={
    \"title\":\"The Hunt for Red October\",
    \"image\":\"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/314leP6WviL._SL500_AA300_.jpg\",
    \"url\":\"https://link.you.want.displayed/example/hunt-for-red-october-link\",
    \"description\":\"Classic cold war technothriller\",
    \"data\": {
      \"isbn\":\"425240339\"
    }
  }"
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#publishing

For **create an app access token**:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

I dont know how exactly translate this code in php but I think very probably you can do this easy.

I hope this is useful for you.
Sorry if I dont focus your question.

Comment: you can also pass the $APP_TOKEN as YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_SECRET, however if he's having the same problems I am facing, the Open Graph object is getting created and returning an id.  I can verify the id in the debugger, but when I got to post the url as a status update it doesn't lookup the object and instead tries to scrape the url which isn't live yet.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need turn on "Explicitly Shared - This action can specify the user explicitly shared an action." in settings of your app on facebook
go Graph --> Actions --> choose on action --> capabilities